# Decreasing velocity of my space ship

Tags: c#, xna

I'm writing a space game for Windows Phone in some good ol' discontinued XNA. I need the velocity of the ship to decrease gradually until it gets to zero when the user is not holding the drive button. It sounds simple but Velocity is a Vector2 and I don't know how to do this.

```
        position += velocity;
        speed = 0.04f;

        switch (driveBtn.CurrentButtonState) 
        {
            case ControlButton.ButtonState.Released:
                //Need to slow down ship when drive is not being held.
                break;

            case ControlButton.ButtonState.Pressing:
                velocity.X += (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * speed;
                velocity.Y += (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * speed;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: so just add a very small vector that exactly opposes the ship's motion

Comment: If velocity is a vector, the just add `-velocity/factor` where `factor` is the numeric value that scales how slow or fast you loose speed. Once velocity's magnitude is zero you stop adding.

Comment: Ah, my mistake (it's been a long day...)  However, you should rename `speed` to `acceleration` to achieve greater code clarity.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No problem, will do.

Comment: _"but Velocity is a Vector2 and I don't know how to do this"_ - considering that you are already doing vector math via `velocity.X += (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * speed` I find it surprising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dividing velocity:

```
velocity /= 2f;
```

Comment: You'll never get to zero!

Comment: Thanks mate! That worked :) I have to wait 7 minutes to mark this as an answer but ill wait.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Just tested. It takes 150 iterations to get from `1` to below `float.Epsilon`. That's 2.5 sec at 60 fps. But your definition of "zero" may be different...

Comment: +1 The only possible issue with this solution is that the acceleration is not constant. You would loose speed really fast in the first few iterations and very little towards the end. If thats ok, then this is the simplest implementation.

Comment: It also needs to be a function of **GameTime.ElapsedGameTime** to be accurate

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which may provide you with a smoother, and more controllable rate, you could use linear interpolation:

```
float rate = 0.5f;
velocity = Vector2.Lerp(velocity, Vector2.Zero, rate);
```